# Are there two roots for time in projectile equation because the projectile ascends & descends?

Tags: kinematics, projectile

#### Question

We can take the kinematic equations for constant acceleration and apply them to projectiles in free fall. One of the equations then reads:

$$\Delta y=(v_0\sin \theta )t-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$$

where $v_0$ is the projectile's initial velocity, $\theta$ is the angle of projection, $g$ is the gravitational field strength, and $t$ is the time taken to reach some vertical displacement $\Delta y$.

Rearranging into a quadratic function gives:

$$\frac{1}{2}gt^2-(v_0\sin \theta)t+\Delta y=0$$

and this has the roots:

$$t=\frac{v_0 \sin \theta ±\sqrt{(v_0\sin\theta)^2-2g\Delta y}}{g}$$

I have always thought that there are two roots because any projectile reaches the displacement $\Delta y$ at two moments: once while ascending and once while descending. Is this the correct way to interpret the roots? Does this physical interpretation *always* hold true, or are there exceptions?

#### Motivation

A colleague and I both solved [this projectile question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UAHHM3-sSlM) by Walter Lewin. I used the "+" when dealing with the two roots, and he used the "-". We both acquired the same result ($t=1.549\text{ s}$), but using two different methods. I don't want to post all of the details of our solutions because it would be too lengthy. I'm trying to figure out the mistake in my work or in my colleague's work, and our two approaches are mainly distinguished by how we dealt with the two roots for $t$.

Comment: For anyone interested, my colleague essentially solved the quadratic twice: once using the conditions x = 10, y > 8 and then a second time using the conditions x = 15, y = 8. (Before solving for the roots, he did some substitution using other equations, e.g., $vtcosθ = x$) Then he found where the two lines intersected to get the minimum time. But when solving for the roots he used the "-", arguing that we seek the smallest time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do negative times and negative distances represent in parametric projectile equations?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/132821/)

Comment: @sammygerbil, thanks for the link. I've removed that question about negative time to focus my question only one what isn't found elsewhere on the site.

Comment: If you both got the same answer by different methods, why do you think one of you made a mistake? Problems can often be solved by different methods. If they make the same assumptions they always lead to the same answer.

Comment: @sammygerbil, you've hit the nail on the head--this is exactly why I'm asking the question. If neither of us made a mistake, then my understanding about how to interpret the two roots is flawed.

Comment: Yes the reason is that one time applies for ascent and one for descent. ... The link you gave is not a projectile motion question. ... I don't follow your reasoning that if neither of you made a mistake then  your interpretation of the two roots must be flawed.

Comment: Woops--I've updated the link. Both of us solved for the time it takes to reach the target. We both agree that the ball is on its descent (not its ascent) when it hits the target. And we both acquired the same answer. But my colleague used the root which has a "-" sign, while I used the root which has a "+" sign.

Comment: As I said, different methods of solution are possible. If applied correctly they should arrive at the same answer. If they arrive at different answers one method has been applied incorrectly. You arrived at the same answer, therefore there is no requirement that one method was wrong. You are asking for an explanation of something which requires no explanation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79244/discussion-between-jdphysics-and-sammy-gerbil).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have always thought that there are two roots because any projectile reaches the displacement $\Delta y$ at two moments: once while ascending and once while descending. Is this the correct way to interpret the roots? Does this physical interpretation *always* hold true, or are there exceptions?

Yes. This is what the two roots represent. There's obviously trouble when they meet and vanish (i.e. you're asking for a $\Delta y$ that's too large for the initial velocity) but so long as they're real, they must have those characteristics.